# Laravel returns wrong data for given id

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a table `products` which has a record with `id = 1` and `alias = 'some-alias'`.

When I run `Product::find(1)`, I get incorrect alias value:

```
{
  id: 1,
  alias: "another-alias",
}
```

The same is for `DB::raw()` and `DB::table()` queries.

If I change alias from `some-alias` to `some-alias-1` and than change it back to `some-alias` the query returns correct data:

```
{
  id: 1,
  alias: "some-alias",
}
```

I use Laravel 5.8 and Postgres 11.5.

Comment: Is there some caching layer in Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this syntax:

```
Product::where('id', 1)->first();
```

or

```
Product::where('alias', 'some-alias')->first();
```

Comment: No, same result with Product::where('id', 1)->first() and Product::whereId(1)->first(). It looks like the results are stored in some kind of a buffer. I worked with MySQL and switched to Postgres just recently and cannot wrap my head around about all it's features so far.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me, if you send a request without using laravel, will the result be the same?

I'm not sure, but maybe the reason is in transaction isolation level? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html

Which isolation level has your database?

Comment: Yes, I logged into Postgres docker container directly and executed raw sql queries there. Same result. Moreover, in some parts of the app eloquent returns correct data for the very same `Product::where('id', 1)->first()`. 

I don't know about isolation level. Gotta check it.